# Is there a way to invoke ansible playbook from Jenkins when ansible is running on a remote server

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, devops, jenkins-cli

I have ansible engine running on server 1 and Jenkins running on server2. Is there a way to execute the playbook from the Jenkins server using any of the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Can you login to Server1(Ansible) from Server2 (Jenkins) using SSH and execute command ansible?
Or can Server1(Ansible) be converted into a Jenkins Slave, connect it with Jenkins (Server2) and configure your job to run on Server1 where ansible is installed.

Comment: So the First approach which you are suggesting is like using "Execute shell on remote server" and  In the second approach we will have an extra overhead of having a slave Jenkins.
Is there any Better or efficient way?

Comment: Yes, either user "Execute shell on remote server" or execute ssh command using "Execute Shell". If you are using Jenkins Pipeline, you can use "sh"/"sshagent" under "steps". Something like mentioned below GitHub repo:

https://gist.github.com/mrhockeymonkey/adf7a462982340cdad2ef4f65b481227

Better approach is having Ansible installed on Jenkins server itself :)